# An image of the hierarchy of algebraic structures

Tags: mathematics-education, abstract-algebra

Hello! Does anybody know an image of a graph featuring the hierarchy of algebraic structures? Something rather complete.

So far I've found similar images describing the hierarchies of classes/categories in various programming languages. For example

- [Haskell's basic algebra library](http://ubuntuone.com/p/19TS/)
- [Coq's math classes](http://math-classes.org/hierarchy.png)
- So far the largest Axiom's [abbreviated](http://www.axiom-developer.org/axiom-website/dotabb.html) and [full name](http://daly.axiom-developer.org/dotfull.html) graph of its categories (incomplete?)
- [category hierarchy of Sage](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/attachment/wiki/CategoriesRoadMap/sage-category-graph.pdf)

Comment: "Something rather complete" sounds like too tall an order. There must be thousands of algebraic structures that mathematicians are interested in. 

Answer (score 10):

Page 2 of "[Is 'the theory of everything' merely the ultimate ensemble theory?](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9704009)" by Max Tegmark contains the following image:

[image: Relationships between various basic mathematical structures]

Comment: What on earth are double fields and triple fields??? Also, why does the dodecahedron group belong to that chart? ...strange choices.

Comment: +1 to André's comment. However much I respect physics and physicists, I personally think the article in question is a truly bizarre choice of a reference when it comes to dealing with algebraic structures.

Comment: There are some pieces one might consider useful, but a lot of it inspires a resounding "LOLWUT"

Answer (score 7):

This is sort of a delayed response, but I came upon this question while googling for the visualization of the hierarchy of structures used in the Coq proof of the Feit-Thompson Odd Order theorem. That visualization is [located here](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/), image copied below:[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to a higher res version. The link you gave is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can complement the image from Mark Kim with the algebraic structures between magmas and groups:

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup